# www vs non-www for User Experience?

Tags: urls

Which one do you think is more memorable/ looks better? The pros of www are that it may look better, but I heard that it's depreciated due to the face that it has no real meaning. would domain.com be better?

Comment: The site is http://magvato.com or http://www.magvato.com.

Comment: I don't think you can get an answer to this but consider that several major sites favor the "www" version: www.google.com, www.yahoo.com, www.apple.com and for that reason my preference is to use that version as well.  Things may change with the new top level domains coming out (e.g. `.computer`)

Answer (score 4):

1. The shorter is better
2. It is better to support subdomain www and to redirect requests to parent domain (i.e. without www)
3. Your real UX fault is misleading users with site name you've posted (magvato.com) and the real web address (magmoz.com)

Answer (score 0):

### For User Experience

**Non www, for sure**. But regardless of your choice, **redirect the other to the chosen one**. A user comes to know that WWW could type least While such non-www not received an error page. Do not redirect could cause a bad user experience and sometimes SEO problens if search engine make some mistake.

### For technical reasons

This answer depends because of way of cookies works. The answer still "non www" if:

- Is a *small* site. Will not have subdomains soon
- If you want serve your CSS, JS and images optimized for performance will use another domain and never your subdomain.

Remember, **this choice can affect not only performance but also security** in some specific cases, because a subdomain could steal cookies generated by the primary domain or just waste bits on each user request for every file.